# How to make rearrangeable objects and display them for every user

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, backend

Title is maybe confusing but I will try to explain what is that I need.

I have application that shows tables of some place (e.g restaurant). This tables are shown to end user.
But I want owner to be able to rearrange these tables position from admin panel. He will be presented container ( just a rectangle to keep it simple ) and I want them to be able to take table (it can be icon or whatever) and place it wherever they want (literally in any direction or position in this container). They can add as many tables as they want and place them where they want. This part is for frontend and I am not too scared of this. But problem for me is how can I save this information using Laravel? because I want owner to save this position of tables and then when end user comes to page of that place I want them to see the positioning of these tables that owner provided.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

I don't need Laravel specific answer, just to point me in right direction so I can understand the logic of how this can be saved on backend.

I am using Vue.js on frontend and Laravel for backend.

I made this sketch so you can see what I mean : https://prnt.sc/1tcv3lf

Comment: Considering that objects are positioned with CSS, you need to store on back end actual offsets in pixels or some values that they could be calculated from (e.g. normalized to 100%).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Will use this. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

**Frontend**

In Vue, you can implement a reusable component for the tables. These components will have a `top` and a `left` props which define their absolute position from the container's top and left (CSS rules). You can easily make them draggable using jQuery by calculating mouse pointer's position relative to the container's top-left corner. Pass them as props into top and left for the table components. Store them in an array `[{ top: _, left: _ }]`. Append to this array whenever a new table is added.
When save button is clicked send this array to the backend.

**Backend**

Not sure what exactly is bothering you about this, you can simply store it in a database with `top` and `left` columns, each row representing one table in your frontend.

Then you can query this database to fetch all rows whenever users visit the page, pass it as an array to the frontend. The frontend will use this array to construct all the tables in the right positions.

Comment: I was overcomplicating this in my head. This is great solution and will try it. Once I implement and solve the problem I will close the thread.  Thanks for reply, really appreciate it!

Comment: Sure. Let me know how it goes!